# Raise Event For Changed Cell Value In Table

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, dataset, odbc

I'm trying to raise an event if a cell's value has changed.
from within a [.tps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarion_(programming_language)) file.
I have so far been able to connect to the database via [odbc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/310988/how-to-use-the-odbc-net-managed-provider-in-visual-c-net-and-connectio) which is great for a database of its age and I have also been able to use an SQL query to get what data I need.
Here is my issue, I'm hoping to be able to raise an event when a particular columns cell/cells have changed.
I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency) for SQL however there doesn't seem to be anything similar withing the Odbc library.
So one way I was thinking was to have two [DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=netframework-4.7.2) objects and if the 1st dataset object is null, then we will load the table required into there and eventually after a certain period,
 if the 1st dataset was not empty then we would set the 2nd dataset to equal the 1st, and then we would load the new table into the 1st dataset after clearing the previous table from it.
From there we would run this loop :
Here is my workaround, surely there is an easier way without having this much overhead.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Compare DataSet2 to DataSet1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ds1">DataSet1</param>
    /// <param name="ds2">DataSet2</param>
    /// <param name="tableName">Tables Name</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private void CompareTables(string tableName, DataSet ds1, DataSet ds2)
    {
        int index = 0;

        foreach (DataRow dw1 in ds1.Tables[tableName].Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dw2 in ds2.Tables[tableName].Rows)
            {
                if (dw1.ToString() != dw1.ToString())
                {
                    Console.Write(dw1.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(index);
                    SomethingHasChanged = true;
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Before but the above code, we would first need to get the data, 
So I created this.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the Tables Data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tableName">select your tables name.</param>
    private void DownloadTable(string tableName)
    {
        using (OdbcConnection odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            string DOWNLOAD_TABLE = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
            if (OpenConnectionAsync(odbcConnection).Result)
            {
                if (DataSet1 == null)
                {
                    OdbcCommand odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(DOWNLOAD_TABLE, odbcConnection);
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Load(odbcCommand.ExecuteReader());

                    DataSet1 = new DataSet();
                    DataSet1.Tables.Add(dataTable);
                }
                else if (DataSet1 != null)
                {
                    // DataSet 2 is now DataSet 1
                    DataSet2 = DataSet1;

                    OdbcCommand odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(DOWNLOAD_TABLE, odbcConnection);
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Load(odbcCommand.ExecuteReader());

                    DataSet1.Clear();
                    DataSet1.Tables.Add(dataTable);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Data Downloaded");
        }
```

The function below is what I have created to trigger the events above.

```
    private void WaitForChanges()
    {
        if (SomethingHasChanged)
        {
            // do something on change.
        }
        else
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            DownloadTable("foo");
        }
    }
```

And finally here is the constructor and the properties I am using

```
    private DataSet DataSet1 { get; set; }
    private DataSet DataSet2 { get; set; }
    private Boolean SomethingHasChanged { get; set; }
    private string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create A New DB Manager Object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
    public DBManager(string connectionString = @"Dsn=pChoice_WDC;")
    {
        Task task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (IsValidConnection(connectionString))
            {
                ConnectionString = connectionString;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Connection String Error");
            }
        });

        Task.WaitAny(task);
        WaitForChanges();
    }
```